# Vertical ButtonBar buttons width

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, buttonbar

I am creating a vertical button bar with 3 buttons.
How do I force the same width for all three buttons so it doesn't look like crap?

```
<s:ButtonBar x="10" y="10" dataProvider="{viewstack1}" >
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="-1"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:ButtonBar>
<mx:ViewStack id="viewstack1" left="115" paddingRight="0" right="0" bottom="0" top="0">
    <s:NavigatorContent label="ABC Products" width="100%" height="100%"><custom:Banner  width="100%" height="100%"/></s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Btn Player" width="100%" height="100%"><custom:Player /></s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Btn Cleaner" width="100%" height="100%"><custom:Cleaner width="100%"/></s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that problem too so I dropped s:VerticalLayout and used s:TileLayout with a fixed column width and it worked

```
<s:ButtonBar width="142" dataProvider="{almacen}" left="10" top="10">
   <s:layout>
      <s:TileLayout columnWidth="142"/>
   </s:layout>
</s:ButtonBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to **define the gap**, in order to avoid **distance between the buttons**

```
<s:layout>
   <s:TileLayout verticalGap="-1" />
</s:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without forcing the width or setting the columnWidth in tile layout you can achieve the same result using horizontalAlign property of the vertical layout.

```
<s:ButtonBar id="btnBarVertical1" dataProvider="{menuData}" requireSelection="true" labelField="label">
      <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="-1" horizontalAlign="justify"/>
      </s:layout>
</s:ButtonBar>
```

For icon based button bar apply the same property with iconPlacement to top like this...

```
<s:ButtonBar id="btnBarVertical2" dataProvider="{menuDataWithIcon}" requireSelection="true" labelField="label" 
                iconField="icon" iconPlacement="top">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout gap="-1" horizontalAlign="justify"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:ButtonBar>
```

I hope this will help for dynamic text lengths...

Happy Flexing.